# Smooth curve through points and include the origin in R

Tags: r, plot

I am a beginner in R and started with graphics recently.

I have managed to program a working empirical cumulative distribution function (user-generated, not using the standard ecdf() function) and to generate a plot. However, the plot is not as it should be, there are two issues with it and I am not sure on how to solve them (I have done my 'research' but have not found a solution).

This is my code:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 50

x = rpois(n, 2.2)

cdf = function(x,n)
{
  v=c()
  for(z in 1:max(x))
  {
    a = length(x[x<=z])/n
    v = c(v, a)
  }
  plot(v,type="l", main="empirical cumulative distribution function",   xlab="x", ylab="cumulative probability", xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,1.0))

}
cdf(x, n)
```

There are two issues with this plot:

1. The lines are straight but it should be a smooth curve through all points.
2. The origin is not included (now the curve starts at x = 1).

How can these issues be resolved in an elegant way?

Comment: Perhaps see `?ecdf`?

Comment: No, I do not want to use the standard built-in function ecdf(). Suggestions to my function (preferably additions to the plot() function) are welcome.

Comment: Replace `v=c()` with `v = 0`, and change your plot call to `plot(0:max(x),v,type="l", .......)`. For as smooth line you'll have to do some extra work. Have a look at `?loess` for example.

Comment: I took a look at loes() and lowess() but it seems the smoothing effect is minimal. I think that is due to my data. Do you think it is possible to create a nice smooth curve?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following spline interpolator:

```
plot(spline(c(0, v)), type = "l")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it!